# Ionic 4 binding input data with interface not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ngmodel

I have interface as follow in Ionic :

```
// mydata.model.ts
export interface Mydata{
   id: string;
   name: string;
   date: string
}
```

I'd like to add a new data to the backend so i'm binding my data within my component inside the `<ion-input>` as follow :

```
// add-data.page.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Mydata } from '../home/mydata.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-data',
  templateUrl: './add-data.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-data.page.scss'],
})
export class AddDataPage implements OnInit {
  thedata: Mydata;

  constructor(private dk: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit(){


  }

   showData(){
    console.log(this.thedata);
  }
}
```

And here is my add-data components :

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating">Name</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="thedata.name" name="myname"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating">Date</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="thedata.date" name="mydate"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-button padding expand="full" size="medium" (click)="showData()">
    <ion-icon name="add-circle" slot="start"></ion-icon> Add Data
  </ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

My question is why did the data binding not working in this situation?

I mean I cannot print the data in console.

I got an error message:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

I could however print the data in console if I changed the value of `[(ngModel)]` with string type data. So to make my question more clear, what is the correct way of binding input data with interface in Angular?

Comment: it should be `thedata: Mydata;` capital "M"

Comment: My bad. It's a typo. Still not working though. The error is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the interface to be able to bind it in the template, example:

```
thedata : Mydata =
{
  id     : "1",
  name   : "john",
  date   : "01/02/2019"
}
```

Then you can do `(ngModel)]="thedata.name"`

Answer (score 1):

you need to initialize object to use keys or you can use class with constructor.

First way:

```
    // mydata.model.ts
export class Mydata{
   id: string;
   name: string;
   date: string
   constructor(){
      this.id = "";
      this.name = "";
      this.date = "";
   }
}
```

on your component.ts

```
theData: MyData = new MyData()
```

Second Way:

```
// mydata.model.ts
export interface Mydata{
   id: string;
   name: string;
   date: string
}
```

at your component.ts

```
theData: MyData = {id="", name: "", date: ""};
```